# sudo prompt in terminal doesn't enter

Tags: sudo, spotify

I am trying to install Spotify on Ubuntu 16.04. I type the command into the terminal sudo apt-key adv... etc. and hit enter. It prompts me for the password and when I type on the keyboard nothing happens. How do I get this to work?

Comment: What do you mean by nothing happens? Nothing being typed or an error returned?

Comment: the keyboard doesn't work when i type

Answer (score 3):

It's for Security purposes you will be not able to see anything when you are typing your password, so that others can't guess your password by looking at number of characters or so...

You just type your Password and type enter.

To install an application we are supposed to use the `sudo apt-get install` command followed by the name of the package one wishes to install.